# TimeZone.getDefault() returns different values when run in a static block

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am seeing an issue which is new to me, even though I have used SimpleDateFormat for date parsing/formatting for 10 years.  I am running locally (no external data center) in Central Time Zone.  My problem is that my SimpleDateFormat (which depends on TimeZone.getDefault()) has different defaulted timezones in different code blocks:

```
String myDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
static {
    System.out.println("default A: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
}

SimpleDateFormat sdfA = new SimpleDateFormat(myDatePattern);

public void run(String... strings) {
    System.out.println("default B: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat sdfB = new SimpleDateFormat(myDatePattern);
    System.out.println("sdfA timezone: " + sdfA.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println("sdfB timezone: " + sdfB.getTimeZone());
}
```

which gives this output:

```
default A: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Chicago"...
default B: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT"...
sdfA timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Chicago"...
sdfB timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT"...
```

So a SimpleDateFormat object defined at the class level gets different timezone defaults compared to the same object defined inside a method!

Comment: Works fine for me. Show us the code that runs this code.

Comment: Works fine for me, too.

Comment: so someone changed the default timezone between these two calls

Comment: you are correct wero!  i should have thought of this...  if you post it as an answer I will accept it!